# Why did my XSLT transformation drop most XML tags?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XML and XSLT. What I'm trying to do is a XSLT transformation that matches any element type album/name from my XML document and transforms their values into a link. What I've got so far does half of that. I'm stumped on how to get the links in. Any advice on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Edit: using `xsltproc -o new_inventory.xml music_inventory.xsl music_inventory.xml` with the below XML and XSLT, it seems that it is putting the links in as I desired, but I get the error message that the document is empty when I try to view from a browser.

Here is new_inventory.xml created by the above command. (Notice how there are no  XML tags around any elements accept the link.)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


  Led Zepplin
  <id><a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="LEDZEP.xhtml">Mothership</a$
  1968
  Atlantic
  1
  1

   Good Times Bad Times
   Communication Breakdown
   Dazed and Confused
   Babe I'm gonna Leave You
   Whole Lotta Love
   Ramble On
   Heartbreaker
   Immigrant Song
   Since I've Been Loving You
```

**XML:**

```
<music_inventory>
 <album id="LEDZEP" type="full_length" albumart="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cb/Led_Zeppelin_-_Mothership.jpg">
  <artist>Led Zepplin</artist>
  <name>Mothership</name>
  <year>1968</year>
  <label>Atlantic</label>
  <disc>1</disc>
  <totaldiscs>1</totaldiscs>
  <tracklist>
   <track id="1">Good Times Bad Times</track>
   <track id="2">Communication Breakdown</track>
   <track id="3">Dazed and Confused</track>
   <track id="4">Babe I'm gonna Leave You</track>
   <track id="5">Whole Lotta Love</track>
   <track id="6">Ramble On</track>
   <track id="7">Heartbreaker</track>
   <track id="8">Immigrant Song</track>
   <track id="9">Since I've Been Loving You</track>
   <track id="10">Rock and Roll</track>
   <track id="11">Black Dog</track>
   <track id="12">When the Levee Breaks</track>
   <track id="13">Stairway to Heaven</track>
  </tracklist>
 </album>
 <album id="SUBL" type="full_length" albumart="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/94/Sublime_Self-Titled.jpg/220px-Sublime_Self-Titled.jpg">
  <artist>Sublime</artist>
  <name>Sublime</name>
  <year>1996</year>
  <label>MCA</label>
  <disc>1</disc>
  <totaldiscs>1</totaldiscs>
  <tracklist>
   <track id="1">Garden Grove</track>
   <track id="2">What I Got</track>
   <track id="3">Wrong Way</track>
   <track id="4">Same in the End</track>
   <track id="5">April 29, 1992 (Miami)</track>
   <track id="6">Santeria</track>
   <track id="7">Seed</track>
   <track id="8">Jailhouse</track>
   <track id="9">Pawn Shop</track>
   <track id="10">Paddle Out</track>
   <track id="11">The Ballad of Johnny Butt</track>
   <track id="12">Burritos</track>
   <track id="13">Under My Voodoo</track>
   <track id="14">Get Ready</track>
   <track id="15">Caress Me Down</track>
   <track id="16">What I Got (Reprise)</track>
   <track id="17">Doin' Time</track>
  </tracklist>
 </album>
</music_inventory>
```

**XSLT**

```
   <xsl:template match="album/name">
    <id>
     <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      href="{../@id}.xhtml">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </a>
    </id>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you show us the expected output of the transformation?

Comment: Thanks for the response @michael.hor257k, please see above I've made some edits to my question.   I expect a new xml file (new_inventory.xml) that identical to the the original xml except hyperlinks that use the id for the server name (either subl or ledzep) and uses the the attributes in the artist tag for the hyperlink text.

Comment: Please post your expected result **as code**, not as a description. In particular, this part "*hyperlinks that use the id for the server name (either subl or ledzep)*" is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> notice how there are no xml tags around any elements accept the link

If you add the identity transformation to your XSLT,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="album/name">
    <id>
      <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         href="{../@id}.xhtml">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </a>
    </id>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You'll get the missing XML tags back along with your links:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><music_inventory>
 <album id="LEDZEP" type="full_length" albumart="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cb/Led_Zeppelin_-_Mothership.jpg">
  <artist>Led Zepplin</artist>
  <id><a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="LEDZEP.xhtml">Mothership</a></id>
  <year>1968</year>
  <label>Atlantic</label>
  <disc>1</disc>
  <totaldiscs>1</totaldiscs>
  <tracklist>
   <track id="1">Good Times Bad Times</track>
   <track id="2">Communication Breakdown</track>
   <track id="3">Dazed and Confused</track>
   <track id="4">Babe I'm gonna Leave You</track>
   <track id="5">Whole Lotta Love</track>
   <track id="6">Ramble On</track>
   <track id="7">Heartbreaker</track>
   <track id="8">Immigrant Song</track>
   <track id="9">Since I've Been Loving You</track>
   <track id="10">Rock and Roll</track>
   <track id="11">Black Dog</track>
   <track id="12">When the Levee Breaks</track>
   <track id="13">Stairway to Heaven</track>
  </tracklist>
 </album>
 <album id="SUBL" type="full_length" albumart="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/94/Sublime_Self-Titled.jpg/220px-Sublime_Self-Titled.jpg">
  <artist>Sublime</artist>
  <id><a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="SUBL.xhtml">Sublime</a></id>
  <year>1996</year>
  <label>MCA</label>
  <disc>1</disc>
  <totaldiscs>1</totaldiscs>
  <tracklist>
   <track id="1">Garden Grove</track>
   <track id="2">What I Got</track>
   <track id="3">Wrong Way</track>
   <track id="4">Same in the End</track>
   <track id="5">April 29, 1992 (Miami)</track>
   <track id="6">Santeria</track>
   <track id="7">Seed</track>
   <track id="8">Jailhouse</track>
   <track id="9">Pawn Shop</track>
   <track id="10">Paddle Out</track>
   <track id="11">The Ballad of Johnny Butt</track>
   <track id="12">Burritos</track>
   <track id="13">Under My Voodoo</track>
   <track id="14">Get Ready</track>
   <track id="15">Caress Me Down</track>
   <track id="16">What I Got (Reprise)</track>
   <track id="17">Doin' Time</track>
  </tracklist>
 </album>
</music_inventory>
```